# Occupancy probability probem

Tags: probability, area

I have a small (?) probability problem regarding the occupancy area of an object. If an objects centre of mass is given in Cartesian coordinates as [x,y] where x~N($\mu_x$,$\sigma_x$) and y~N($\mu_x$,$\sigma_y$). Now if the area of the object is given as A and the CM is assumed to be in the centre of this area, how does distribution of the occupancy area look like ?

My initial thought would be somewhere along the lines of $\sigma_{x,new}$ = $\sigma_x$ + R , but I'm pretty sure that is completely wrong.

Hope you can help! :)

**EDIT:** I guess it's also possible to look at it first from a 1d perspective. A middle point of a line is given by x~N($\mu_x$,$\sigma_x$) where y = 0. Now if we know the length of the line is L, what is the occupancy probability of that line on the axis ?

Comment: What is occupancy area?

Comment: An area where an object can potentially occupy with a certain probability, at least here :)

I guess it's kind of misleading, the only thing I'm interested in if I know the distribution of the centre, how would the distribution of the rest of the object look like combined. The distribution generated from that can be considered as the probable occupancy area of that object.

This is generally what I'm trying to do: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupancy_grid_mapping

Comment: Hm unfortunately the resulting formula for the 1d case does not appear to have a closed form. You basically have to know the CDF of a Chi distribution, which involves a regularised gamma function.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom

Could you elaborate a little? :)
I've done some simulations, and in Matlab I can approximate this by using the following assumption:

For a probability distribution, the probability density between [-3sigma,3sigma] ~ 99.7%, so then the "new" sigma can be approximated by 6sigma_New = 6sigma + L

But I'd rather be able to do this mathematically if possible

Comment: Well, we want to calculate $\mathbb{P}[| X - z | < L] $. Now if we imagine L to be variable and z to be fixed, then $| X - z |$ follows a noncentral Chi distribution (with one degree of freedom), or a folded normal distribution. We can look at the CDF of such a distribution to see if there is a nice formula for this probability, but it turns out there is none.